# How to check if a zephyr thread crashed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, zephyr-rtos

I start a thread in zephyr like this:

```
K_THREAD_DEFINE(my_name, STACKSIZE, my_func, NULL, NULL,
        NULL, PRIORITY, 0, 0);
```

but it does crash after some time. How do I check it's status to restart it when it crashed?

Comment: Perhaps better not to let it crash in the first place? In any case AFAIK threads cannot crash, only exit. If a thread crashes the whole process crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The uart shell has a command that prints all threads running. It is registered as the function `cmd_kernel_threads` (at `zephyr\subsys\shell\modules\kernel_service.c:144` for my version). Starting from there you should find your info.

```
static int cmd_kernel_threads(const struct shell *shell,
                  size_t argc, char **argv)
{
    ARG_UNUSED(argc);
    ARG_UNUSED(argv);

    shell_print(shell, "Scheduler: %u since last call", sys_clock_elapsed());
    shell_print(shell, "Threads:");
    k_thread_foreach(shell_tdata_dump, (void *)shell);
    return 0;
}
```

I could be wrong but I believe you wont be able to access the thread chained list (`_kernel.threads` in `thread.c`). There should be a better way but you can write a callback to give to `k_thread_foreach` instead of `shell_tdata_dump`. In this callback you'd look sequentially for a thread named as yours.